# Putty executing a text tile in a linux terminal

Tags: linux, powershell, batch-file

I have a one liner that I run from the run box in the start menu:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\casper\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh "192.168.1.2" -l casper -pw "<password>" -m \\PROD.MSAD.casp.NET\UserData\CASPER\Home\Documents\pbauth_list.txt -t
```

It sssh to a linux box, and opens up a terminal and echos these statements intoa terminal. when someone needs elevated access at the linux terminal i just type in user=user than cut and paste the line into the command line - and viola that user has access to a super user account for what ever time period i designate. It works awesome.

The

```
 \\PROD.MSAD.casp.NET\UserData\CASPER\Home\Documents\pbauth_list.txt text
```

file looks like this

```
echo "pbrun pbauthcl grant PBAUTH_P_A4_PROD \$user 2 \"\$user needs access\" now all
pbrun pbauthcl grant PBAUTH_P_A4_UTIL \$user 2 \"\$user needs access\" now all
printf '\e[8;50;100t' 

"
```

Notice that the

```
"printf '\e[8;50;100t'"
```

is echoed out along with the lines into the terminal .

What this command does is automagically logs into a linux box at 192.168.1.2 and then opens up a terminal and prints the lines to the terminal. 
i cut and paste the print statement "printf '\e[8;50;100t'" to resize the terminal. 
When a user wants elevated access at the linux command prompt
What I do is type in user= and then cut and paste one of the pbun command and it gets executed at the linux command line - which works fine.

however it would be much cooler if the  "printf '\e[8;50;100t'" would just execute and make the terminal larger instead of me having to echo it into the terminal and then cut and paste it into the same terminal to resize it. 
I have tried a bunch of different permutations in the test file to get the printf statement to just run, instead of echoing it out. 
bash -v echo "printf '\e[8;50;100t'"

bash ;

I get thse kinds of errors though

```
/usr/bin/printf: /usr/bin/printf: cannot execute binary file 
/bin/echo: /bin/echo: cannot execute binary file
```

how do I execute the "printf '\e[8;50;100t'"
 command within the terminal instead of echoing it out ? There has to be a way .

Answer (score 0):

Two possibile solutions that might work for you are the following:

1. Try `-x`
2. Try `-o verbose`